# Prefix tuning in LLM uses learnable vectors to fine tune the model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer

I would like to implement a new architecture for Transformer.

Below description is my thought.

Prefix tuning in LLM uses learnable vectors to fine tune the model.

Is there a way to use the output generated by the Neural network as prefix?

Thanks

[image]